# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: updates, repositories

I just tried to run an update and got this message from the app center:

[image]

I've tried reading around but all the potential answers I've found go over my head. I'm not really sure what I'm doing re: messing with repositories. Does it seem like a line has somehow been changed in sources.list? What should be there?

UPDATE:

Upon suggestion, I tried

> sudo ppa-purge ppa:versable/elementary-update

And I got:

> W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
>
> E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>
> 404  Not Found
>
> E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>
> Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've installed the following third party ppa: https://launchpad.net/~versable/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-update

I would recommend removing it using ppa-purge:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:versable/elementary-update
```

If you don't want to remove the packages that you've installed with this ppa you should contact them. But it looks like the project is no longer maintained, but then again I have a hard time understanding Launchpad.

Comment: Cheers for the answer. So, this error message doesn't neccesarily mean I'm going to miss proper updates? Just for some thing I installed?

Comment: Yes. As far as I know, when there is an issue with one of the ppa's there is no way to upgrade without removing /fixing that ppa. (I don't like how fragile it is). It's probably one of the reasons elementary OS discourages installing custom ppa's. So, I would strongly recommend removing that ppa. ppa-purge will list what would be removed when removing a ppa.

Comment: Hm, for some reason ppa-purge didn't work. It says the same thing as the pop up:

'sudo ppa-purge ppa:versable/elementary-update
Updating packages lists
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason'

And I looked up the repo and it's Tweaks

Comment: What was the output of using `ppa-purge`? Did that give an error? (You could also update your question, that would give you more formatting options)

Comment: Because I was curious I  opened: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/596

Comment: Hey, thanks again. I updated the original question with the output of ppa-purge.