# Can't upgrade my packages

Tags: updates, apt, package-management

Short version: I can't upgrade my packages (I'm using Elementary OS 0.4.1, based on Ubuntu - that's why I'm asking here).

Long version:

**First step**
I try fetching package informations via `sudo apt-get update`. Besides the fact that I get a really long list in the output (snippet below) it seems that it works properly.

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybre/elementaryplus/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107 kB]
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki InRelease
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki Release
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/js-reynaud/kicad-4/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:12 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:13 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial InRelease
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mmk2410/intellij-idea/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:19 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki InRelease
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:25 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki Release
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/simonschneegans/testing/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-de
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release
Hit:39 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted all Packages
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-de
Ign:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse all Packages
Ign:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-de
Ign:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Ign:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-de
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted all Packages
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-de
Ign:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse all Packages
Ign:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-de
Ign:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-de
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted all Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-de
Ign:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse all Packages
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-de
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Err:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:52 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-de
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:62 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-de
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted all Packages
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:66 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-de
Ign:68 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse all Packages
Ign:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-de
Ign:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Err:31 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::1c 80]
Ign:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en_US
Ign:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-en
Ign:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe Translation-de
Ign:37 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:44 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner all Packages
Ign:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted all Packages
Ign:47 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en_US
Ign:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-en
Ign:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted Translation-de
Ign:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:54 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-en
Ign:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/restricted DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse all Packages
Ign:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-en
Ign:63 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse Translation-de
Ign:64 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:67 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:60 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner Translation-de
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main all Packages
Ign:65 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en_US
Ign:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main Translation-de
Ign:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:69 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki/partner DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki/universe all Packages
Fetched 216 kB in 5s (36,5 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu loki Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/loki/partner/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8c01::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/loki/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::21 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Second Step**
As I said above, I thought this might be okay because I have been able to upgrade my packages before.

The next thing I try is doing a `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But when I do this it fails with a bunch of errors:

The error I get the most is `insserv: Starting smfpd depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility '$all' which can not be true!`

Full Error output:
[Output of sudo apt-get upgrade](https://pastebin.com/u4AjSzrK)

**So here's my final question**
What can I do to make these errors disappear?
I have already tried to reconfigure these packages via `dpkg-reconfigure -a` and also a "normal" configuration with `dpkg --configure -a` - both failed.

I would be very thankful for every tip / idea.

Answer (score 0):

First off, most repositories don't have a explicit `loki` distro, and the `apt update` output confirms that: most of them are ignored or not found. I would first remove all of them using one of the ways described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60595/how-to-undo-sudo-add-apt-repository).

And as for Versable: [The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-versable-elementary-update-ubuntu-xenia)